# Zend php can not use rowCount for affected row

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, row

I update row in DB and check for affected row but its not working with rowCount() and also mysql_affected_rows.

This is my code

```
$result = $this->_db_table->update(array('password' => $new_password), $where);
```

I have checked in my DB and it changes pass but when i

```
$affectedRows = mysql_affected_rows($result);
```

or

```
$affectedRows = $result->rowCount();
```

it's always return FALSE with mysql_affected_rows and 500 error server with rowCount(). I test by curl , Any ideas???

Comment: Is it really boolean false or is it 0? Look at this comment on the documentation page for rowCount() http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php#104930. MySQL will return 0 if the update uses identical information as what is already there. There is a work around in PHP 5.3.

Comment: thanks but I have tried $affectedRows = $result->rowCount(); but it does not work. It returns 500 Server Error.

Comment: @erik i user var_dump() and it really is boolean FALES.

Comment: Interesting. What version of PHP and MySQL? I've looked through the c source code and I only see row_count being returned as a RETURN_LONG if it is 0 or greater. (master branch with all commits current as of a few days ago)

Comment: @erik I use phpMyAdmin - 2.10.3 (so it is MySQL client version: 5.0.51a) and php 5.4. how can i solve my problem, thanks.

Comment: @Hai, I'm sorry to say I don't think I will be able to help. I've switched to that branch and both 'grep RETURN_FALSE pdo*' and 'grep RETURN_BOOL pdo*' return no hits. So there are no instances in which any of the PDO functions will return a boolean value (in other words, where the return value "=== false" would be true). Perhaps if you posted more of your code.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/c6gfp23gc8brv45/UserMapper.php this is my code, you can check changepassUser, i commented // some lines ...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that content is actually changed ? If an update it will only return 1 if an actual record was changed rather than the method itself being called. If no change was made then the method will return 0.

Comment: I'm sure that the content change, I always check it after I run. I don't know why but its return FALSE not 0.